# Android DataBindingUtil.inflate always returns null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an issue with DataBindingUtil.inflate as it is always returning null. The project layout it is based on https://www.javatips.net/api/android-architecture-components-master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/MainActivity.java but using androidx.databinding instead of android.databinding.

**res/layout/fragment_app_loading.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/global__primary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_default__image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_icon" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**ui/apploading/AppLoadingFragment.java**

```java
import com.test.hello.binding.FragmentDataBindingComponent;
import com.test.hello.databinding.FragmentAppLoadingBinding;

public class AppLoadingFragment extends Fragment implements Injectable {

    private final androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent = new FragmentDataBindingComponent(this);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        FragmentAppLoadingBinding dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_app_loading,
                container,
                false,
                dataBindingComponent
        );

        AutoClearedValue<FragmentAppLoadingBinding> binding = new AutoClearedValue<>(this, dataBinding);
        return binding.get().getRoot();
    }
}
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0-alpha01"

    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"

    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
```

*I can build and run the application if I disable this screen*. But when I use it, the following happens:

- application starts
- the screen defined in **fragment_app_loading.xml** is showing up
- the application crashes: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.test.hello.databinding.FragmentAppLoadingBinding.getRoot()' on a null object reference`

I am stuck. I think I have tried everything I could. Am I missing something obvious?